# how to write query in sparql to extract this specific data from dbpedia? Is it feasible or not, if yes what should be query?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

This is a [link](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Cloud_computing_providers) I would like to query it

I want to extract list of the cloud providers and then through each cloud provider I extract their abstraction, their company link and their name, in case of they have product name I want that too.for example in case of aws:"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services",there is a content table which is important for me and I don't know how I can extract that particular properties.
Please if somebody have any experience for such cases I will be appreciated to help me.

Comment: What do you mean by the content table?

Comment: when you open page in wikipedia , in the left side there is a table called content which you are able to hide that. I mean that table. However i couldn't find this table with similar content in dbpedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a query to retrieve companies that are active in could computing `category:Cloud_computing_providers` with their name `foaf:name` and their webpage `foaf:homepage` is quite straightforward.

```
select distinct *
where {
    ?company dcterms:subject category:Cloud_computing_providers.
    ?company foaf:name ?name.
    ?company foaf:homepage ?homepage
}
```

I don't know what you mean by abstraction. Do you mean the description of the company? If so you need to add the following line to the query `?company dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract`.

As you pointed out, not all the companies have product (`dbpedia-owl:product`). So you need to add an optional point to this query:

```
select distinct *
where {
    ?company dcterms:subject category:Cloud_computing_providers.
    ?company foaf:name ?name.
    ?company foaf:homepage ?homepage.
    ?company dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
    Optional{?company dbpedia-owl:product ?product.}
}
```

I have no idea what you mean by the content table either. You need to clarify what you need. But to filter it only for amazon web services, you need to add it to the end of the query:

```
select distinct *
where {
    ?company dcterms:subject category:Cloud_computing_providers.
    ?company foaf:name ?name.
    ?company foaf:homepage ?homepage.
    ?company dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
    Optional{?company dbpedia-owl:product ?product.}
    Filter (str(?name)="Amazon Web Services")
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. I mean from content of web page when you are going to webpage en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services in the left side there is a Contents [hide] table is included table below: 1 Architecture 2 History 3 List of product 3.1 Compute 3.2 ... I need to extract content like list of product. Moreover, i am interesting in only English version.Also, I have tried with Logo, it give back me link of logo, how i can have a picture itself. if you see result you will see that there is a lot of repeated row exists. Do you know what is a solution for this case. thank you in advance @artemis

Comment: You just need to add more variables. For example, `?company dbpprop:logo ?logo.` But the problem is that not all of the results have all the variables, e.g. for fujitso(http://dbpedia.org/page/Fujitsu), you don't have architecture, so if you don't put it in the optional tag it won't come out. Edit your question for me to add more to the answer. Otherwise it would be vague for others. Also, don't look at dbpedia the way you look at wiki, not all the infer exists in dbpedia.

Comment: sorry, i am new with stackoverflow. I try to change my question.But my last question, my output is like http://dbpedia.org/resource/Beijing , that is only last part is important for me"Beijing",is there any way to represent the last part not a link through query or i should write parser for that? @artemis

Comment: You can ask for `dbpedia:Beijing rdfs:label ?label` and the `?label` should give you Beijing.

Comment: It is not working, even i changed to ?country rdfs:label ?label,still didnt work...moreover, your comment is only for Beijing instead i need to apply this rules for all the properties.like location,product,..  @artemis

Comment: Post a new question. I don't follow what you are saying anymore. Sorry.